# How to create image with imagemagick without any other ruby gems?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5

i want to create a image with imagemagick without any wrapper or binding like rmagick for rspec and learing purpose. please suggest me how to do it. Without any gem how can i create an image

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a solid color image using the ImageMagick command line, then

```
convert -size 100x100 xc:red red.png
```

[image]

Comment: how do i do it for rspec as i need to validate the picture size.

Comment: Your question says without rmagick for rspec. Sorry I know little about either, only ImageMagick command line.